# How does one get the Tags of an AWS resource by its ARN?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, devops

I'm working on a service that I want to use to monitor tags and enforce tagging policies.

One planned feature is to detect resources that are tagged with a value that is not allowed for the respective key.

I can already list the ARNs of resources that have a certain tag-key and I am now looking to filter this list of resources according to invalid values. To do that I want to query a list of each resources tags using its ARN and then filter by those that have invalid values in their tags.

I have

```
[{
    "ResourceArn":"arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1:123:xyz",
    "ResourceType":"AWS::Service::Something
}, ...]
```

and I want to do something like

`queryTags("arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1:123:xyz")`

to get the tags of the specified resource.

I'm using nodejs, but I'm happy to use a solution based on the AWS cli or anything else that can be used in a script.

Comment: You will need to write out all that logic, nothing like that exists in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that through awscli.

For example, EC2 has the command describe-tags for listing the tags of resources and I think other resources also have command like this. It also has options that meet your need.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html